# Add Fragment at Runtime, set its layout at runtime, no layout xml files involved in Android

Tags: android, fragment

I have an activity that creates its layout dynamically in onCreate.  It looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    /*
     laying out screen at runtime (activity_main.xml is not used).
     */
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
            100);
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    // instantiate my class that does drawing on Canvas
    bubble = new Bubble(this);
    bubble .setLayoutParams(lp);
    bubble .setBackgroundColor(MY_COLOR);
    ll.addView(bubble);
    setContentView(ll);
}
```

So, there is no layout at all and that is how it should stay.

I would like to add fragment instead of code above, then as part of the fragment onCreate(), instantiate my Bubble class to do drawing.  The fragment should also not have any layout defined in layout XML file but it should all be at runtime.

Much appreciated,

Comment: What's the question, exactly? You just need to move your `View` instantiations to a `Fragment`'s `onCreateView()` method, and call `return ll;` instead of `setContentView(ll);`. You don't even really need the `LinearLayout`, if `Bubble` is the only `View` the `Fragment`'s going to have.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I am very new to Android development so I need bit more info.  I am also reading about it and I guess my activity also has to extend FragmentActivity, not AppCompatActivity(which is doing now)?  By the way, I am using min sdk 5.0 (API21).

Comment: Nah, you're good - `AppCompatActivity extends FragmentActivity`.

Comment: Since I dont have layout file for my fragment I have to use this to add it to frag manager  getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(keplerFragment, TAG_KEPLER_FRAGMENT);  but that does not show it.  If I am reading correctly Google docs, adding fragment this way will add fragment without UI but in my case, I do have UI, it is just created at runtime without layout xml file?

Comment: Your Activity needs to have in its layout a ViewGroup - usually a FrameLayout - that will hold the Fragment. Then you would use one of the `FragmentTransaction#add()` methods that takes an `int` for the first argument, which will be the ID for the ViewGroup in the Activity; e.g., `R.id.container`.

Comment: That works, thanks.  The reason I wanted to do this is to be able to retain my fragment.  So, I added my fragment onCreate() setRetainInstance(true) but my app crashes on rotation with "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment study.android.bubble.BubbleFragment did not create a view" error.  Any idea?  Thanks

Comment: Not without seeing your code and stacktrace, but that would have to be a new question. Try searching the site for that error first, though. I know I've seen questions with that error before.

Comment: @MikeM.  Thank you very much.  I'd mark your reply as answer but I cannot for some reason, it only allows me to up/down vote your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reworking your code to use `Fragment`s is pretty straightforward. Move the `View` declarations to the `Fragment`, move the instantiations to its `onCreateView()` method, and return the parent `ViewGroup`. For example:

```
public class BubbleFragment extends Fragment
{
    Bubble bubble;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        /*
         laying out screen at runtime (activity_main.xml is not used).
         */
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
            100);
        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        // instantiate my class that does drawing on Canvas
        bubble = new Bubble(getActivity());
        bubble.setLayoutParams(lp);
        bubble.setBackgroundColor(MY_COLOR);
        ll.addView(bubble);

        return ll;
    }
}
```

Please note that the `View`s' constructors' arguments have been changed to `getActivity()`, since a `Fragment` is not a `Context`. Also, if no more `View`s are going to be added to the `Fragment`, you could omit the `LinearLayout`, and just return the `Bubble` object.

The `Activity` will need its own layout that includes a `ViewGroup` - commonly a `FrameLayout` - to hold the `Fragment`. Whether you use a predefined XML layout or generate it dynamically doesn't matter. You just need an ID for the `ViewGroup` that you can pass to one of the `FragmentTransaction#add()` methods. For example:

```
BubbleFragment keplerFragment = new BubbleFragment(...);
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.content, keplerFragment, TAG_KEPLER_FRAGMENT);
```

And, as mentioned in comments, since `AppCompatActivity extends FragmentActivity`, you don't need to change your `Activity`'s superclass.

Comment: I created new question re issue I have with orientation change at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33113562/android-orientation-change-crashes-application  Thank you so much for your help on this one Mike.  Much appreciated.