# Android Orientation Change Crashes Application

Tags: android, fragment, android-orientation, device-orientation

I have an activity with simple layout file that will hold a fragment created and added to it programmatically.  The fragment does not have any layout file since I create layout programmatically as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/bubble_fragment">

</LinearLayout>
```

My Fragment's onCreateView() is like this and it will create layout and class Bubble which does some drawing on Canvas using Handler (android.os.Handler):

```
public class Bubble extends View implements View.OnClickListener {

    private static final boolean BUBBLING = true; //thread is running to draw

    private Paint paint;
    private ShapeDrawable bubble;

    // coordiantes, radius etc
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int r;
    private int w = 200;
    private int h = 200;

    //handler to invalidate (force redraw on main GUI thread from this thread)
    private Handler handler = new Handler();

    public Bubble(Context context) {
        super(context);
        x = w/2;
        y = h/2;
        r = w/2;

        bubble = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
        bubble.getPaint().setColor(Color.BLUE);
        bubble.setBounds(0, 0, r, r);

        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged  (int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh){
        //set bubble parameters (center, size, etc)

        startAnimation();
    }

    public void startAnimation(){
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (BUBBLING) {
                    moveBubble();

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(50);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                    }

                    //update by invalidating on main UI thread
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            invalidate();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }


    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        // draws bubble on canvas
    }

    private void moveBubble(){
        x = x + 1;
        y = y + 1;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(this.getContext(), "Tapped on screen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

I am using setRetainInstance(true) to retain my fragmnet state.  Everything seems to be working fine and my drawing works and refreshes itself just fine.  However, on orientation change, I get this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
     at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3936)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3786)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3727)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3700)
     at my.study.android.bubble.BubbleFragment.onCreateView(BubbleFragment.java:52)
```

From what I have read so far, using inflator like this

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.camera_fragment, parent, false);
```

should solve this problem but in my case, I do not use inflater, I create layout for my fragment dynamically.

**UPDATE**
Here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="my.study.android.bubble" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            >
            <!-- removed this from above to show ActionBar
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"> -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

UPDATE 2:
I figure out why it was crashing.  I was creating Bubble inside onCreate().  If I move it to onCreateView(), then on orientation, it will not crash.
However, my animation is not retained on orientation, meaning the bubble is draws at its initial location when I change orientation:

```
public class BubbleFragment extends Fragment {

    Bubble bubble;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //retain fragment
        setRetainInstance(true);

        //bubble = new Bubble(getActivity()); //THIS WILL CRASH APP, MOVE TO onCreateView instetad
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                100);
        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        // instantiate my class that does drawing on Canvas
        bubble = new Bubble(getActivity());
        bubble.setLayoutParams(lp);
        bubble.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        ll.addView(bubble);  //if you create bubble in onCreate() this will crash.  Create bubble in onCreateView

        return ll;
    }
}
```

Much appreciated,

Comment: You're giving bubble a parent, and then attempting to add it to the parent. You can (please correct me on this) use `null` instead of parent in `inflater.inflate`.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian.  The bubble c-tor is receiving context.  Take a look at the onCreateView above, I am not using infleter at all.

Comment: Due to the retainInstanceState set to true, the fragment is not recreated. Thus, the view is already added. I would probably just check whether the view is added or not by using a findViewById and doing a null check.

Comment: I think the problem is in the `Bubble` class. I can only imagine that the `Bubble` constructor adds the new instance to a parent view. Can we see the code?

Comment: @haitanya  I am already checking for the existence of the view.  I traced the code and it will find the view, so it is not added again.

Comment: @PaulBoddington see the update.  Thanks

Comment: @dbnex14 Can you include the constructor in full?

Comment: There should be something missing. Can you provide the full code? Because all of this looks well not to have any leak or something that is producing your error.

Comment: @PaulBoddington  I have added c-tor in full

Comment: @dbnex14 Ok well I'm completely wrong. The problem isn't in there. Have you tried getting rid of the line `bubble.setLayoutParams(lp);` and doing `ll.addView(bubble, lp);` instead?

Comment: @PaulBoddington yes, same error happens now on line ll.addView(bubble, lp);

Comment: @dbnex14 Have you tried (cleaning and) rebuilding your project? I can't reproduce the error you're getting.

Comment: @MikeM. Do you mind posting your code so I can compare to mine.  I have tried cleaning and rebuilding, no success.

Comment: If you mean `ll.addView(bubble)`, then yeah, I've got that. I just copied your code and ran it. Did you add any attributes to the `<activity>` element in your manifest, other than the defaults?

Comment: I just removed NoActionBar theme so I see action bar, I updated the question above to include the manifest

Comment: @MikeM. I figured out the crash but my animation is not retained on orientation.  My bubble will draw at initial location on orientation change and I would like it to continue where it left off.  I was thinking if I just retain my BubbleFragment that should work?

Comment: @MikeM.  I created another clearer post at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33159777/retaining-fragment/33160134#33160134